# Load and play ultra high resolution vídeos on android

Tags: android, video, crop, resolution

Does anyone know how to load a high resolution video in android programmatically, such as 3000 x 3000, to display only a portion of this video, such as 1000 x 1000?
I tried to use the MediaPlayer android sdk official in a TextureView, but this method has media size limitations, I think, because the video plays but and texture view is black ..

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Media size limitations are for a reason. 3k x 3k resolution video is huge for such small device like phone. Consider that you are not able to decrypt only small portion of video frame, that is not like video works. So you need do decrypt whole big frame (wchich is calculated from I-Frame and following P-frames ) than take screenshot of it after that take part which you are interested in and present on your textureView, and all of this in realtime. Think about device memory and CPU. In my opinion it's not possible with such small resources